# Keyboard enter not working on some phones

Tags: java, android

So I have a problem on my Oneplus 3t that the enter key creates a new line and doesn't actually do action, but on Samsung phones it works fine. This is the EditText

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nav_button"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_button"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxHeight="140dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text="@string/section"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

And this is how I handle the action

```
        mSearch.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (i) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        unReadySeach(section, mSearch, search, mSearch.getText().toString(), mNavButton, backArrow);
                        gridView.setAdapter(new QuoteImageAdapater(getApplicationContext(), reader.getSearchData(mSearch.getText().toString()), section));
                        searched = true;
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also in the virtual device on a pixel 2, when I press on the enter key on the keyboard itself it creates a new line but when I press on enter key on my own keyboard of my pc it does work.

Edit: I fixed it by changing the EditText to this

```
                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchText"
                    android:layout_width="230dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/section"
                    android:background="@drawable/underline"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"
                    android:maxHeight="140dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/textHint"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one because solution you have used, it is not guaranteed for soft keys.

**First Solution:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />


EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

**Second Solution**

```
mSearch.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
               (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
          {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                  unReadySeach(section, mSearch, search, mSearch.getText().toString(), mNavButton, backArrow);
                        gridView.setAdapter(new QuoteImageAdapater(getApplicationContext(), reader.getSearchData(mSearch.getText().toString()), section));
                        searched = true;
                return true;
          }
          return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It still creates a new line. This is what I made it https://hastebin.com/ajuvogaboz.java I added the text inputType and the actionSend imeOptions but now it also doesn't work when I type enter on my keyboard.

Comment: I think you are working with nexus device or version 4.2. Nexus has the issue with soft keyboards. Let me find the another solution.

Comment: My old code worked on samsung phones, this code isn't working on any right now.

Comment: which device you are using for testing ?

Comment: please try second solution.I have edited the answer.

Comment: Nope it still creates a new line